# WP_Query and using a variable for 'cat'=> in the args array = WP Bug?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, bug

For the sake of this discussion, here's a version of my query within category.php:

```
wp_reset_query();
$category_id = get_cat_ID(single_cat_title('', false));
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
'posts_per_page' => SOME_DEFINED_VALUE,
'cat'  => $category_id,
'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
'post_type' => array('post','post_custom_1','post_custom_2','post_custom_3')
));
// print_r($my_query);
```

In short, it doesn't work. Here's what I've noticed.

When I do the print_r($my_query); I can see the query_vars in the first line. They do not match my array args. For example, the posts_per_page defaults to some other value (not the CONSTANT), and the post_type list no longer includes post (which is should / must).

If I remove the line with 'cat'=> or hardcode the value ('cat'=> 3) then every thing works as expected. The remaining query_vars show up in the print_r. Life is good :)

I have tried the following but found no success:

- Making the var into a CONSTANT, just like posts_per_page (which
  doesn't cause a problem).
- Concating quote around the $category_id number - The result is the
  same as no quotes at all. It doesn't work.
- 'cat' => array($category_id) - I pulled an error - It didn't like
  that it was an array.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Now here's what did "work" (read: I could use my $category_id and doing so didn't muck up the rest of the args in the WP_Query() array list).

```
'cat'  => '"-'$category_id'"',
```

That is, I could not that cat ID. Crazy, right?

Unless I can resolve it properly, I'm going to have a comma separated sting of all my cat not'ed, parse out the current cat and then use that string to do the query. In other words if my cats were A, B and C, instead of doing a query for A (as one would expect to do)

```
'cat' => A
```

I'm going to query for not B, not C.

```
'cat' => -B,-C
```

Hopefully there's a less hack-y solution. I've been on this too many hours now and I'm desperate enough to use this hack and be done with it. That said, this sure feel like a bug in the core to me. Yes, I'm using 3.5.1 (or are we up to .2 or .3 now?). My point is, I'm on the latest version (and this did the same in 3.2.x).

btw, I've seen this issue posted elsewhere (e.g. WP forums). The one solution suggested the args array not be an array but a string. Even if that's possible with WP_Query, how would I do the list / array for the post_types as a string? Finally, if I'm doing something  wrong then the Codex help page needs an update, eh?

Help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Where/how are you defining `$category_id`?

Reference [the Codex entry for `WP_Query()` category parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters). `WP_Query()` expects category IDs to be passed as **integers**, not as **strings**:

- If `$category_id` is an *integer*, pass it to `'cat'`.
- If `$category_id` is an *array* (of category *IDs*, again as *integers*), pass it to `'category__in'`

Comment: Thanks @Chip. This line, right above the query:

    $category_id = get_cat_ID(single_cat_title('', false));

If I echo it to screen, it's there and it looks kosher to me. In fact, the query_vars DOES list 'cat'=> the problem is, the per_page and the post_types go wonky. I'm not pulling an undeclared var or type being wrong. As far as I can tell that's not the issue. Any other suggestions? Thx again

Comment: And what does that line return? Try a `var_dump( $category_id )`.

Comment: var_dump( $category_id ) returns: string(1) "7". OH?

Comment: I added / tested this: $category_id = (int)get_cat_ID(single_cat_title('', false));
         var_dump( $category_id ); and WP_Query ignores my args and defaults to something else. Good try but best I can tell the type (string or int) is not the issue. And if I wrap the int $var in '"'.$var.'"' it does NOT work. BUT '"-'.$var.'"'; does. NOT = OK, else my args are dropped and it goes to some defaults (?)

Comment: So, just as a longshot, try type-casting `$category_id` as an integer?

Comment: Like this:  $category_id = (int)get_cat_ID(single_cat_title('', false));  :) Yes, I've already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has to do with the way you get the category. I did set up the function on a blog i'm working on ; `$category_id` is always 0.

So to check I use this line for `$category_id` :

```
global $post;
$category_id = get_the_category($post->ID)[0]->term_id;
```

Just a quick way to get the first category assigned to a post.

After that, the query was ok and the `cat`parameter on the query gets populated.

Comment: Thx @Simon. Allow me to clarify a bit. The 'cat' => $var does work (kinda). I shows up in the query_var. However, when using a $var to do that assignment, other things go wonky (e.g. posts_per_page, post_type, etc.). I'm not getting an error. What's happening is the arg array I us in WP_Query() doesn't match what I see in the print_r() *when I try to assign 'cat' => with a $var. Yeah, wrap your head around that :) Also, I'm trying to use the line of code you mention and I'm pulling: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' . ??

Comment: I add the `global $post`, i guess this is what throws the parse error, sorry.

I did not notice on my tests anything wrong except the empty `$category_id`. 

Just a note, I don't use print_r which is difficult to read, I use the console plugin which allow you to see variables in the firebug console. It's very handy and makes reading much easier

Comment: Well...I had added the global $post; myself the first time and still pulled the error. I guess that's why I was asking. Strange, right?

Comment: Ok, this should work only on a single page, not category page, sorry I missed that ! It's interesting, but there is probably an explaination to your problem.

Comment: I checked your original code in a category.php page and it's working properly. No mess in post_type or post_per_page.

Comment: Thanks again @Simon. I suspect there's some sort of add "leak" elsewhere in the theme. I didn't do the build, I'm just in charge of enhancements. But even so, this is a WP core bug IMHO. I should either we an error / it should bomb, or I should get the results based on the query args. As it is I'm getting a random query when there is a particular (but legit) condition (i.e., 'cat' => $var). Question: Getting the WP bug fixed soon is unlikely, so how about troubleshooting / finding a work around? Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe try to switch theme just to check the behavior and consistency of the returned results. As it's working for me and another guy here, I would suppose there's no bug in core, but some other hook in the theme or a plugin.

Comment: Thx again @Simon. I wish it was as easy as switching themes but this has to do with additional custom post types and such that are build into this custom theme. I spec a query. I make the request. WP use a different set of args. Even if that's another plugin, etc. that's still a bug (to me). It doesn't make sense to allow plugins, etc. and then have no way of knowing which one is accountable for "rejecting" the request and swapping in its own. That doesn't leave much faith in WP_Query, yes? Further more...'cat'=> -1,-3,-4 works but 'cat'=> 2 does not. That too strikes me as a bug, no? :(

Comment: btw, turns out the "not" hack doesn't quite work either. The next_posts_link() displays on the last page. Which leads me to believe that's using a different set of args than I'm submitting with my "not cats" string and other args. Now I'm stuck and stumped.

Comment: Hey @Simon - Thanks for the nudge / push. I finally tracked down an add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'function_to_modify_the_query_in_category_php'). Yup, that function was augmenting the standard query parms. Why there was also code in the category.php I'm not sure. Obviously, I got distracted. That said, it still doesn't explain why 'cat'=> $var made things wonky. Hard coded value ok, $var not ok. That's still pretty odd in my book in a feels like a bug sorta way. But then again, I n00bed this one up pretty good, eh? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: and @Andy Killen. Thanks too for your help / nudge.

Comment: You're welcome @Chief Alchemist. `pre_get_posts`was the right candidate for that behavior.

Comment: As a side note...to anyone reading this...please comment your code. You never know who else might have to work on it. A simple "this query's args are augmented with function: xyz() in functions.php" would have saved me a load time. 10 secs might save someone - including yourself - hours.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your function and it works fine, so you probably have an error with some other code in your theme or a plugin conflict. Or maybe you loop is not correct.

For reference I tested the following code on `category.php` in twentyeleven, the output was correct, without errors.

```
wp_reset_query();
define("SOME_DEFINED_VALUE", 5);

$category_id = get_cat_ID(single_cat_title('', false));

$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
'posts_per_page' => SOME_DEFINED_VALUE,
'cat'  => $category_id,
'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
'post_type' => array('post','post_custom_1','post_custom_2','post_custom_3')
));

var_dump($my_query);
```

Comment: Hi @Wyck - Yes, that is what I'm tending to believe. That is, there's something somewhere else. I presume that because the default values (i.e. what my arg array gets ditched for some other set of query_arr values) have to come from somewhere, eh? But that's what I'm jamming the we_reset on top. Push some to shove that should leave me with a clean slate, yes? Even so, why would setting 'cat'=> (and far as I can tell, only that parm) with a $var be an issue. That level of weirdness feels like a big to me. You? All that said...any thoughts on a solution? Or how to find the theme's bug / hole?

Comment: Check that template page for other loops or it is including other parts of templates (`include` or `get_template_part`), disable them and see if it works, remove widgets from loading, remove plugins, check if anything is hijacking the query via `pre_get_posts`, check if anything else is using your `$my_query` (change the name).

Answer (score 0):

When I spilt up your thing into manageable chunks to analyze them I found that the problem was most likely with the "paged" line in the array.

```
wp_reset_query();
$category_id = get_cat_ID(single_cat_title('', false));

$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') )? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ;

$query = array(
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'cat'  => $category_id,
'paged' => $paged ,
'post_type' => array('post','custom_1','custom_2','custom_3')
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $query);

print_r($loop);
```

As you can see I added an extra bracket around the first `get_query_var` so that it became a proper ternary operator.  I tried this on my test rig and it worked just fine.

regards
Andy

Comment: Thx @Andy Killen. Sad to say it did not help. At this point it much be something somewhere else in the theme. That said, I would expect the wp_reset_query() to give me a clean slate, yes? As it is, 'cat' being assigned with a $val causes WP to seek some other set of args. Those DO look like a set the site is using elsewhere. What I don't understand is why. Why is not using the args I'm asking it to use? And better still, since I'm not pulling any real errors, how should I do abuot trying to pin down this "leak"? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I agree with Wyck (currently below), this is most likely an issue with another plugin or your theme.  I would try disabling all plugins and trying again, and then if that does not do the job, try putting you categories.php into the twentyten theme or similar and trying there. 

The wp_reset_query() is not so vital in this situation.  You could look at this as being a nested loop inside the standard loop if you really wanted, as you are using your own var to store the loop it won't matter so much.

Comment: What if I just did a proper SQL query? That's not going to add any extra overhead, etc., correct? It just seems to me that by the time I track down the source of the "leak" - and I might never be able to do that since the use of a $var triggering a "bug" is just plain odd to begin with, eh - I could just tap out a SQL statement and not have to worry about WP_Query() and its issues.

Comment: Actually, I think my Plan A for now is going to be a string with all the cats not'ed. And then I'll remove the current cat. Opps, I think I already mentioned this as a solutions. Crazy but I'll work. And if I find the hole someday, I can just remove this "hack".